# MediaFramework - Brightcove HTML 5 Player

Tags: brightcove

I am using Media Framework 2.0 with Sitecore 8.0. I have been able to generate a flash player with the Media Framework API. This is the code -

```
args.MarkupType = Sitecore.MediaFramework.Pipelines.MediaGenerateMarkup.MarkupType.Frame;
                    Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Players.BrightcovePlayerMarkupGenerator generator = new Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Players.BrightcovePlayerMarkupGenerator();
                    Sitecore.MediaFramework.Pipelines.MediaGenerateMarkup.MediaGenerateMarkupPipeline.Run(args);
                    return args.Result.Html;
```

But I'm not able to generate the HTML5 player using this code. This only works for Flash based players but not HTML5.

Is there a way in the MediaFramework API to accomplish this or will I have to roll my own code to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a brightcove patch configuration file:

```
Sitecore.MediaFramework.Services.Brightcove.config
```

Review current configuration for `<playerMarkupGenerators>` You will find:

```
<playerMarkupGenerators>
    <add name="brightcove_video" templateId="{6A5C6835-6E11-4602-A11D-B626E9255397}" type="Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Players.BrightcovePlayerMarkupGenerator,Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove">
      <analyticsScriptUrl>/sitecore modules/Web/MediaFramework/js/Analytics/brightcove.js</analyticsScriptUrl>
      <scriptUrl>http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js</scriptUrl>
      <parameters hint="raw:AddParameter">
        <param name="isVid" value="true"/>
        <param name="isUI" value="true"/>
        <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true"/>
        <param name="includeAPI" value="true"/>
        <param name="htmlFallback" value="true"/>
        <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="brightcoveListener.onTemplateReady"/>
      </parameters>
    </add>
    <add name="brightcove_playlist" templateId="{0E24292F-D7A5-4BA2-BCA0-CD5F14A89634}" type="Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove.Players.BrightcovePlayerMarkupGenerator,Sitecore.MediaFramework.Brightcove">
      <analyticsScriptUrl>/sitecore modules/Web/MediaFramework/js/Analytics/brightcove.js</analyticsScriptUrl>
      <scriptUrl>http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js</scriptUrl>
      <parameters hint="raw:AddParameter">
        <param name="isVid" value="true"/>
        <param name="isUI" value="true"/>
        <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true"/>
        <param name="includeAPI" value="true"/>
        <param name="htmlFallback" value="true"/>
        <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="brightcoveListener.onTemplateReady"/>
      </parameters>
    </add>
  </playerMarkupGenerators>
```

As you can see you can change/remove/add some parameters to generate markup.
Try to play with some parameters. As I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229621/html5-video-with-brightcove
you just need to add

`<param name="forceHTML" value="true" />`

I had not chance to test it. Sorry. Maybe you also need to remove/update some default parameters.